# Predicate comparing two fields with DapperExtensions

Tags: c#, dapper-extensions

I am trying to create what seems like a relatively simple predicate statement for Dapper-Extensions in C# after doing a good number of these, but in one case I need to compare two fields rather than a field and a fixed object value:

```
multiPred.Add<ChargingProfile>(new PredicateGroup
{
    Operator = GroupOperator.And,
    Predicates = new List<IPredicate>
    {
        Predicates.Field<ChargingProfile>(f => f.EndDt, Operator.Eq, null, true),

        // the below statement should check if f.NextChargeDt is greater than f.EndDt
        // (string value is obviously not correct, but to illustrate)
        Predicates.Field<ChargingProfile>(f => f.NextChargeDt, Operator.Gt, "f.EndDt")
    }
});
```

I can't (or don't know how to) access the expression in the value parameter, so there must be some other way of doing this?

Thanks for any insights you can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Property` for creating a predicate:

```
var predicate = Predicates.Property<TwoFieldsTable, TwoFieldsTable>(f => f.Field1, Operator.Eq, f2 => f2.Field2);
var res = conn.GetList<TwoFieldsTable>(predicate);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I used this information to update the documentation on the Dapper-Extensions wiki, where this type of predicate was just marked "TODO": https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/Predicates